# Enter data without focalized on a input. Angular 10

Tags: html, angular10

I am doing a little application to enter 2D codes automatically way with a scanner when a product passed for a production line. I am looking for this data it enters, without the need to do focus on the input. So far I have...

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-4"> <label for='panel'><b>Panel</b></label> </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-4">
    <input type="text" name="panel" #panel="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bar_code" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()" class="form-control" required autofocus>
</div>
```

How the scanner add a enter (end of line) I used the event (keyup.enter), and this is working perfect, but the cursor must always be on the input, so if somebody clicks outside of the input, I'll lose trace of some product, until somebody clicks inside again. 
Then, in the component.ts I don't have any problem, because I use a function such as the follow.

```
 onEnter() {
 console.log(this.bar_code);
 //Here is the function for send to backend
 this.bar_code=null;  //let white the imput. 
 }
```